# SQL - Most Common (Repeated) Value In One Column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I Have Completely Shown What I Mean In The Picture

[image]

Please Help Me.

Comment: I Just Love Camel Case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
       p.ID, p.Destination, COUNT(*) AS CountOfTrips
FROM   dbo.tblPath p INNER JOIN dbo.tblTrip t
ON     p.ID = t.Path_ID
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Destination
ORDER BY CountOfTrips DESC
```

Note #1: [TOP WITH TIES](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

Note #2: The difference between `TOP(1)` and `TOP(1) WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT  TOP(1)  
        src.Name, src.Cnt
FROM    (
    SELECT 'A', 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'B', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 'C', 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'D', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 'E', 1
) src(Name,Cnt)
ORDER BY src.Cnt DESC;
/*
Name Cnt
---- ---
B    2
*/
```

vs.

```
SELECT  TOP(1) WITH TIES 
        src.Name, src.Cnt
FROM    (
    SELECT 'A', 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'B', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 'C', 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'D', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 'E', 1
) src(Name,Cnt)
ORDER BY src.Cnt DESC;
/*
Name Cnt
---- ---
B    2
C    2
*/
```

Note #2: You forgot the join predicate/condition (`p.ID = t.Path_ID`) between `dbo.tblPath` and `dbo.tblTrip`. In SQL Server this couldn't be possible with ANSI SQL 92 style joins because the join predicated is mandatory for INNER/LEFT/RIGHT/FULL JOINs.

Answer (score 0):

For Future Visitors:
This Code Solved My Problem:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
       p.ID, p.Destination, COUNT(*) AS CountOfTrips
FROM   dbo.tblPath p INNER JOIN dbo.tblTrip t
ON     p.ID = t.Path_ID
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Destination
ORDER BY CountOfTrips DESC
```